# Adding a space before each item in a multi-item citation

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing, jabref

I am using JabRef with Lyx, and currently when I insert a multi-item citation in my document, it shows up something like this: `[8,10,23]` in the output, without any space before each item (except for the first one).

I wonder if it is possible to add a space in between item, so in the output it will look like `[8, 10, 23]`. If so, please let me know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `cite` package. By default, it will put a small amount of whitespace after each comma. If you want an ordinary interword space after the commas, include the `space` option; i.e., in your document's preamble, you should invoke the package as follows:

```
\usepackage[space]{cite}
```